# How to customise the admin bar in ApostropheCMS?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am new to ApostropheCMS. I went through the documentation and tried out demos of it. I have created a user listing with filters on it as per the tutorial but I have not got the gist of it completely. I was trying to customise the admin bar. How can I do that? Will I have to override the apostrophe-admin-bar module?

Comment: Every piece type you create automatically appears on the admin bar. What are you trying to change?

Comment: Well I have figured out the way. I was trying to customise the complete look and feel of the admin bar. I went ahead and override the **apos-admin-bar** module in my lib and made changes. I hope this is right way?

Comment: Yes. Want to answer your own question and share the solution so I can review?

Answer (score 0):

In Apos-v3 you can edit the `modules\@apostrophecms\admin-bar\index.js` file, to add an item to the groups array.

You can group your modules, like I did for my 'preview', 'navigation' and 'home' pieces :

```js
module.exports = {
    options: {
      groups: [
        {
          name: 'media',
          label: 'Media',
          items: [
            '@apostrophecms/image',
            '@apostrophecms/file',
            '@apostrophecms/image-tag',
            '@apostrophecms/file-tag'
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'home',
          label: 'Gestion Accueil',
          items: [
            'preview',
            'navigation',
            'home'
          ]
        },
]
```